# How to add aud field to a token generated by Azure AD for v1.0 endpoint?

Tags: azure, authentication, security, oauth, azure-active-directory

Hello I am using Azure AD and I am trying to get an access token from the Azure Server by hitting the endpoint at https://sts.windows.net/ the token which I am getting doesn't have the right audience field as it is something like a garbage value 00000002-0000-0010-e000-000000000233. What I need is to get my client id in the aud field of the token.

Any thoughts on this will be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add `aud` field to a token generated by Azure AD for v1.0 endpoint, check the below:**

Create an Azure AD Application:

[image]

***Expose an API and add scope:***

[image]

In the API permissions blade add the permissions:

[image]

To authorize users, I used below authorize endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&resource=ClientID
&state=12345
```

[image]

I generated **access token** by using parameters via *Postman*:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
resource:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

The `aud` is ClientID when I decoded access token:

[image]

To resolve the issue, make sure to pass **`resource`** parameter correctly while generating the token.

Comment: Thanks for the help @rukmini, I have used the endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token as my OIDC server endpoint to get the access token by I am getting an 404 error as 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tentantid>/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration

I am trying to hit the OIDC server directly from my python script using client-credentials flow

Comment: Can you paste the screenshots of what are you trying with the error?

Comment: I am using this python [SDK](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-deploy-sdk#usage) to authenticate myself with the OIDC Server.

Comment: Any ideas on why the endpoint is giving me 404? Any suggestions for using Client Credentials flow?

Comment: to keep this simple, can you please let me know how to do a curl to this endpoint with parameters to retrieve the token using client credentials method with correct aud field as I think that should be enough

Comment: Sure I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for helping on this,looking forward to see how we can get the token from OIDC server when using curl command with client-credentials flow

Comment: Check this `curl -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token -d grant_type=client_credentials -d client_id=ClientID -d client_secret=ClientSecret -d resource=ResourceID`

Comment: Thanks @rukmini where can I get the resourceID from azure AD app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255378/discussion-between-rukmini-and-mahesh).